# If the Witch steals the power of the warlord and tries to destroy a player's district, are they protected if they have the bishop?

Tags: citadels

1. Player A has the witch and bewitches the Warlord.
2. Player A chooses to destroy player B's district.
3. Player B has the Bishop. Can he reveal it to protect himself?
4. If player B can do this and reveal the bishop, can player C rob the bishop with the thief?

Comment: is thesunneversets' correct?  If so, it would be helpful to mark his answer as accepted.  You seem to have a large number of answered questions that aren't accepted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**No**

The Witch doesn't get to destroy a district when she is revealed - she skips her turn after taking an action, and only gets to play when (if!) the Warlord is revealed.  By that time, player B has already been revealed to be the Bishop, and is immune to the bewitched Warlord's power.

Comment: Ug, I've been playing differently and I forgot this was the actual rule. Thanks. :)